# Thermistor - NTC 10 D-9 , steinhart-hart equation

Tags: temperature, thermistor

I have the steinhart equation which is 
1/T = A + B*ln(R) + C*(ln(R))^3

Where can I find an exact datasheet for  NTC 10 D-9 ,(Please attach the exact datasheet with its temperature and resistance table if possible)

so that I can have different values of its resistance at different temperatures to compute my A,B,C coefficients using the below calculator. https://www.thinksrs.com/downloads/programs/therm%20calc/ntccalibrator/ntccalculator.html

It would be very useful for me to suggest even better ways(Iam going to measure the temperature of a dog!)

IMPORTANT:please share the resistance-voltage table if possible!!

Comment: You should get the datasheet through the vendor that sold the thermistor. At the very least, you should try searching the manufacturer's web site for this information. Have you tried either of these approaches?

Comment: No the shop I got the thermistor did not give me any datasheet that is the problem, can you help providing me?

Comment: You should probably just return the thermistor that you have and get one from a reputable vendor who can give you the datasheet. Your alternative at this point is to characterize the thermistor yourself...if you are measuring the body temperature of an animal then you only need to characterize over a narrow range of voltages.

Comment: Thank you so much  , I think I have to do that only . I will find a better thermistor from a good source

Comment: The most basic of web seraches will produce literally dozens of apparently relevant hits. eg searching on ntc 10 d-9 gives [this result](https://www.google.com/search?q=ntc+10+d-9&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&oq=ntc+10+d-9&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l6j69i60.5159j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) - [here is a datasheet](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/1811051712_RUILON-Shenzhen-Ruilongyuan-Elec-NTC-10D-9_C3790.pdf) from that search

Comment: This is a 10 Ohm thermistor - is that really what you wanted? || Useful tutorial [here](https://www.electrodragon.com/use-ntc-10d-9-thermal-sensor/)

Answer (score 1):

> even better ways?

**yes Just learn to search better**

[search here for key words](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=thermal%20sensor)

and use the LM35 10mV/°C

The LM35 device does not require any
external calibration or trimming to provide typical
accuracies of ±¼°C at room temperature and ±¾°C
over a full −55°C to 150°C temperature range.

10pc $10
[image]

Comment: assuming the package meets his requirements.  Thermistors come in a whole bunch of forms

Comment: Sure i think i should check this out , even this is a very good option for measuring temperature. Thank you so much. And also what are the properties I should consider before selecting a thermal sensor?